# Is there any more modern slider form factor smartphone?

Tags: android, smartphones

I just can't get used to smartphones without a physical keyboard.

A couple years ago I obtained *Sony Xperia Mini Pro*, which at the time was the last slider phone released. I'm still using it, but it's getting really old now, the internal storage insufficient for updates of essential apps despite moving everything I could move to SD.

I didn't really follow the phone market ever since, and all I know all the *flagship* phones are just touchscreen, no physical keyboard nowadays. But I don't know if someone didn't attempt a "revival", "niche market" or such releases.

Is there any newer, better smartphone on market, in the slider form factor - newer, better than Xperia Mini Pro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Practically the only android phone I can think of that's got a keyboard these days is a *blackberry*. Specifically the [priv](http://us.blackberry.com/smartphones/priv-by-blackberry/specifications.html). It runs newer versions (6.0 is coming soon(, and flagship specs - it runs a  Qualcomm 8992 Snapdragon 808 Hexa-Core. Not the latest and greatest but reasonably solid, 3gb ram, and seems to have some privacy centric addons.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Quite unfortunate that *this* phone takes a firm stand against rooting - down to blocking sideloading of APKs and disabling the ADB console.

Comment: Yeah. I personally don't root my phones, so I never thought of it as a criteria.